# Weird A appearing when I animate an button in html

Tags: css, html, button

I have a button in html that and I have it so that once the user hovers over the button the text of the button will move to one side and arrows will appear on the other side. However for some reason when I hover over it a funny "A" with a little hat appears. This happens in all the browsers I have tried. Any ideas how to fix it?

The Html is:

```css
.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 250px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.button span:after {
  content: '»';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}
.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Contact us today</span>
</button>
```

[image]

Comment: No A appears to me. The code is ok. maybe you have something else that is going wrong.

Comment: Could you also attach a screenshot in the question?

Comment: Everything fine here too.

Comment: You must have some `A` you accidentally wrote in your `html`. The code you have posted here works correctly.

Comment: Just added a pic there.

Comment: seems to work with anything else put in instead of "»". think it might be a something to do with doing it on a mac not sure though. i just settled for a ">" instead. doesn't look as good but sure it'll be grand.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, it is working fine at my end. Just to rule out all the possibilities, try putting » in double quotes instead of single quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is most likely caused by some discrepancy between the character encoding used in your style sheet, and the character encoding used when rendering your web page.

The `»` character is known as Code Point [U+00BB](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/bb/index.htm) in Unicode. This character can be encoded in a few different ways, for instance when stored in a file. Most notably, it is encoded using the following two [octets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing)) in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8):

```
  Encoding    Character
  --------    ---------
  [c2][bb]    »
```

If your web page is being rendered using an incorrect character encoding, such as Microsofts [cp-1252](http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP1252.TXT) for instance, the same octets will be interpreted as *two* single-octet characters:

```
  Encoding    Character
  --------    ---------
  [c2]        Â
  [bb]        »
```

Most of the characters in the `[a0-bf]` range, in many similar 8-bit character encodings, are directly mapped to the corresponding Unicode code point. By an unfortunate coincidence, when one of these characters is encoded in UTF-8, the resulting octet sequence is exactly the same but with a `[c2]` prefix added to it, making it look like some random character has been added to your web page.

---

My best guess is that your CSS file is stored as UTF-8, but your web page is being rendered using some other character encoding.

What to do:

- **Check your HTTP headers**

  Your server should declare the appropriate character encoding in the `Content-Type` header, like this:

  ```
  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
  ```

  If the `charset` parameter is wrong or missing, you need to fix that.

  There are several online services that can show you the actual HTTP headers sent by your server. If you validate your web page (which you should anyway) using the [W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/), it will tell you which character encoding is actually being used.
- **Check your `<meta>` elements**

  If your web server did *not* declare the character encoding in an HTTP header, the browser will look for a character encoding in the HTML source. Look for a `<meta>` element (in the `<head>` section) like this:

  ```
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="cp-1252">
  ```

  or:

  ```
  <meta charset="cp-1252">
  ```
- If both of the above are present, the browser should obey the HTTP header, and only if the character encoding is missing from the HTTP header should it consider the `<meta>` element.
- If the character encoding is not declared through *any* of the above  methods, the browser will fall back to a default setting or user configuration.

Exactly how to set the correct HTTP header depends on what web server you are using.

---

There are also other possible causes, such as double-encoded UTF-8, to consider. You may have to resort to downloading your *rendered* web page, and checking it, as well as your source files, in a hex viewer to find out exactly what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the charset in your css too.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@charset)